# Is it possible to allocate misaligned objects in the following case?

Tags: c++

Suppose we have some valid type T. Given the following code:

```
char* p = static_cast<char*>(malloc(sizeof(T) * 32));
T* t1 = new (p) T;
p += sizeof(T);
T* t2 = new (p) T;
...
```

Is it now possible for `t2` to not be aligned correctly according to its alignment restrictions?

Comment: Can you please show what you're using to _restrict alignments_? Usually that sticks to the type, if you used something like `#pragma pack(x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what `T` is. The guarantees are same as if you had stored the pointer directly into `T*`. If a pointer P is aligned to N byte boundary, then P+N is also aligned to N. Also, the size must be a multiple of the alignment. `malloc`'d memory is guaranteed to be aligned up to the alignment of `max_align_t`.

The pointer is not guaranteed to be aligned for `T` if it is an *over aligned* type i.e. a type with higher alignment requirement than `max_align_t`.

Answer (score 0):

It will be properly aligned, but note that pointer arithmetic is done in multiples of the type size so the

```
p += sizeof(T);
```

will advance the pointer by sizeof(T) units rather than 1. "++p;" would give the next T unit.

Comment: `p` is a `char *`, so it is necessary to add `sizeof(T)`.   If you were referring to incrementing `t1`, your comment about pointer arithmetic would be correct.

Comment: i dont think so. p is `char *` not `T*`